# Email with attached file

Tags: symfony

I want to get an attachment from a received email.

An attachment has as value the file's path.

I want this attachement to be clickable to download the attached file.

Of course i used Swift Mailer library to send emails.

Comment: Did you read the doc ? http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try this!

```
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance();
        $attachment = \Swift_Attachment::fromPath(
            $file_path,
            $mime_type
        );
        $message->attach($attachment);
```